Polly Http Circuit Breaker Break only on Timeout Exception
We have a vendor that goes down a lot. We no longer want the circuit to break when they pass us back 500 errors, etc.. We just want the circuit to break when there is a Timeout Exception.
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> circuitBreaker = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)
    .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(
        failureThreshold: 0.25,
        samplingDuration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300),
        minimumThroughput: 50,
        durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

services.AddHttpClient<IFinancialDetailsService, FinancialDetailsService>()
        .AddPolicyHandler(circuitBreaker);

How can I do this via Polly? HandleTransientHttpError handles 5XX and 408 errors, but I don't see any other extension methods besides that and OrTransientHttpError which does the same thing.

The HandleTransientHttpError handles 408, 5XX status codes and HttpRequestException. It is important to understand that HttpClient does not throw TimeoutException directly. Rather than it is wrapped inside a TaskCanceledException since .NET 5:
try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(downstreamServiceUrl);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
{
   ...
}

For earlier .NET versions you have to examine the CancellationTokenSource to determine whether is it a cancelled or a timed out request.
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync(downstreamServiceUrl, cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex) when (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    ...  
}

So, if you are using .NET 5 or above you have to add the following clause to your policy builder (before the .AdvanceCircuitBreakerAsync):
.Or<TaskCanceledException>(ex => ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)

If you are using earlier .NET version then:
.Or<TaskCanceledException>(_ => !cts.IsCancellationRequested)


Update #1
If you want to handle only timeout scenarios then you don't need to use the HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError() method. Rather than you can define your policy simply like this:
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> circuitBreaker = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<TaskCanceledException>(ex => ex.InnerException is TimeoutException)
    .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(...

OR
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> circuitBreaker = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<TaskCanceledException>(_ => !cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(...


The inner exception is not a timeout exception. This is what I get when I loop through the the inner exceptions:
Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException, Message: The operation was canceled.
Exception: System.IO.IOException, Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, Message: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
In catch statement it's timeout exception...Help

This difference occurs because Polly captures exceptions earlier in the pipeline, possibly before the full propagation of the exception chain is complete, while the catch block captures the fully unwrapped exception after it has been processed by the underlying system (in this case, HttpClient).

My code...
return Policy
.Handle(ex => {
Exception currentException = ex;
while (currentException != null)
{
Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {currentException.GetType()}, Message: {currentException.Message}");
currentException = currentException.InnerException;
}
return ex.InnerException is TimeoutException;
}
)
.AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(...

@GabrielWhitehair Which .net version are you using?

@GabrielWhitehair Also could you please share what value do you use for the HttpClient's Timeout property?

We are using .NET 8 and the latest package versions for Polly. Everything is up to date. This is how we set the timeout:
services.ConfigureAll(options =>
{
options.HttpClientActions.Add(client =>
{
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(config.TimeOutSeconds == null ? 30 : config.TimeOutSeconds));
});
});

@GabrielWhitehair Could you please check the value of the IsCancellationRequested? It is accessible via the TaskCanceledException's CancellationToken property.
